# Fill array in Firebase Cloud Functions from Firebase database

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have a function thats triggered `onWrite()` and I successfully load the data I want. The thing I am having a hard time trying to solve is when later in that function I want to load a list with tokens stored in the database.

This is what I've got so far.

```
const root = event.data.ref.root
const loadMembers = root.child(`groups/${nameOfGroup}/members`).once('value')
const users = loadMembers.then( snap => {
    const members = snap.val()

    // something like this
   // const members = user.child({id})
})
```

Is there a way to do that?

The data is stored like this.

```
{ ekXL3hQyBsNaYaPYudHRySahX5s2: 
   { emailAddress: 'notMyRealEmail123@gmail.com',
     firstName: 'user 1',
     token: 'token4life',
     lastName: '1 User',
     phoneNumber: '+1112222' },
  syRUK9NG11TSHYLMRWbxCFhf2eJ3: 
   { emailAddress: 'user2@gmail.cool',
     firstName: 'User 2',
     id: 'token2m8s',
     lastName: '2 User',
     phoneNumber: '+111111111' }
```

Comment: @DougStevson edited.

Comment: Where is your cloud function that is triggered by onWrite()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want something like this:

```
const root = event.data.ref.root
const loadMembers = root.child(`groups/${nameOfGroup}/members`).once('value')
const users = loadMembers.then( snap => {
    const members = snap.val()
    console.log(members);

    snap.forEach(function(childSnap) {
        console.log(childSnap.val());

        var email = childSnap.child("emailAddress").val();
        var token = childSnap.child("token").val();

        console.log("Token: " + token);
    });
 })
```